# Mada me o mirenai

Tags: meaning

It's a manga title that has two versions of translation. The first is "can't look into his eyes yet" the second is "still can't see"  'me' means eyes so I'm inclined to think the first is right?

Comment: The big question is whether or not to explain ら抜き言葉 to a romaji-using Japanese-learner.

Answer (score 2):

The literal translation of まだ目を見れない is of course "(Someone) cannot look at (someone's) eyes yet." This *usually* implies someone is feeling too embarrassed or guilty against the other person. "Still can't see" is not the literal translation, but I feel it's not necessarily wrong because it may also imply the similar feeling (for example "I still can't see him because I did something terrible and don't know how to apologize"). It depends on the context and the story, anyway.

Comment: Why can't "I still can't see your eyes" be a literal translation? I know it's less likely, but what's wrong grammatically? Should  を be replaced with が, for that translation? I'm never sure about を in potential clauses.

Comment: @user3856370 That's also a literal translation that is likely to fit the context.